Why only LLC miss ratio increase?
On my server, I have a latency critical (LC) task running on NUMA0. To increase utilization, I have also deployed some best-effort (BE) tasks on the same NUMA0. Furthermore, I have enabled some isolation features of cgroup to protect the LC task. Despite this, I found the performance of the LC tasks has decreased. Using perf stat, I discovered that the IPC of the LC task dropped from 1.3 to 1.2 after deploying BE tasks. I attempted to use "perf sata -e" with some raw event counters to see the micro-architectural metrics of the LC task. I noticed that the L1 and L2 miss ratios remained the same after deploying the BE task, while the L3 miss ratios increased from 6% to 9%.
I also tried to use intel RDT to limit the LLC occupancy of the BE tasks. The total ways of my LLC cache is 12, so I limit BE tasks to use only 1/12. However, the phenomenon remains the same（the L3 cache miss ratios is still around 9%）. Limiting the memory bandwidth usage of BE tasks to 10% does not help as well.
Currently, I have no idea how to analyze further to figure out why only L3 miss ratios increased and what the root cause of this phenomenon is.
I hope to get some help here. Sincerely thanks!
Here is my CPU info and perf reports before and after deploying BE tasks.
I have been run perf for several times and the results are almost the same.
cpu info
chitecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                128
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-127
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    32
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 106
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8352Y CPU @ 2.20GHz
Stepping:              6
CPU MHz:               2799.999
CPU max MHz:           3400.0000
CPU min MHz:           800.0000
BogoMIPS:              4400.00
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             48K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              1280K
L3 cache:              49152K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-31,64-95
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     32-63,96-127

perf stat of the LC task before deploying be tasks
 2,507,581,247,482      instructions              #    1.31  insn per cycle           (57.70%)
 1,919,207,125,419      cycles                                                        (64.09%)
     6,577,501,022      L2_RQSTS.DEMAND_DATA_RD_MISS                                     (64.05%)
    20,740,750,037      L2_RQSTS.ALL_DEMAND_DATA_RD                                     (64.02%)
     6,935,557,793      L2_RQSTS.ALL_RFO                                              (64.03%)
     1,534,425,251      L2_RQSTS.RFO_MISS                                             (64.07%)
       574,045,503      OFFCORE_REQUESTS.L3_MISS_DEMAND_DATA_RD                                     (64.01%)
       342,337,011      MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L3_MISS                                      (64.10%)
     5,867,009,991      MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L2_MISS                                      (64.01%)
    16,980,212,379      MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L1_MISS                                      (63.95%)
   308,951,137,867      MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L1_HIT                                       (51.37%)
    10,758,173,508      MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L2_HIT                                       (51.37%)
     5,975,591,272      MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L3_HIT                                       (51.42%)
   306,291,575,807      MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.ALL_LOADS                                     (51.50%)
   188,045,958,463      MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.ALL_STORES                                     (51.36%)

     120.099298650 seconds time elapsed

The L2 & L3 cache miss ratios are calculated as following:  
L2 miss% =  MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L2_MISS / MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L1_MISS = 5,867,009,991 / 16,980,212,379 = 34.5%
L3 miss% = MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L3_MISS / MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L2_MISS =  342,337,011 / 5,867,009,991 = 5.8%

perf stat of the LC task after deploying be tasks
 2,608,552,205,051      instructions              #    1.19  insn per cycle           (57.53%)
 2,183,570,198,313      cycles                                                        (63.94%)
     7,745,052,206      L2_RQSTS.DEMAND_DATA_RD_MISS                                     (64.01%)
    23,073,900,674      L2_RQSTS.ALL_DEMAND_DATA_RD                                     (64.01%)
     7,164,922,408      L2_RQSTS.ALL_RFO                                              (64.03%)
     1,661,683,201      L2_RQSTS.RFO_MISS                                             (64.05%)
       825,912,577      OFFCORE_REQUESTS.L3_MISS_DEMAND_DATA_RD                                     (64.02%)
       583,675,847      MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L3_MISS                                      (64.05%)
     6,438,858,223      MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L2_MISS                                      (63.99%)
    18,199,655,787      MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L1_MISS                                      (63.84%)
   320,077,134,491      MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L1_HIT                                       (51.25%)
    11,351,727,437      MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L2_HIT                                       (51.22%)
     6,275,779,430      MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L3_HIT                                       (51.16%)
   318,136,944,465      MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.ALL_LOADS                                     (51.27%)
   195,803,999,110      MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.ALL_STORES                                     (51.34%)

     120.116917905 seconds time elapsed
     
L2 miss% = L2 miss / l1 miss = 6,438,858,223 / 18,199,655,787 = 35.3%
L3 miss% = L3 miss /l2 miss =  583,675,847 / 6,438,858,223 = 9.1%

perf stat of the LC task after deploying be tasks and limit LLC occupancy.
 2,637,374,229,407      instructions              #    1.18  insn per cycle           (50.91%)
 2,232,720,790,691      cycles                                                        (56.61%)
     7,766,059,047      L2_RQSTS.DEMAND_DATA_RD_MISS                                     (56.68%)
    22,716,753,053      L2_RQSTS.ALL_DEMAND_DATA_RD                                     (56.70%)
     6,872,784,090      L2_RQSTS.ALL_RFO                                              (56.70%)
     1,679,610,667      L2_RQSTS.RFO_MISS                                             (56.67%)
       885,846,658      OFFCORE_REQUESTS.L3_MISS_DEMAND_DATA_RD                                     (56.67%)
       646,751,270      MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L3_MISS                                      (56.59%)
     6,877,904,780      MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L2_MISS                                      (56.42%)
    18,698,108,046      MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L1_MISS                                      (56.33%)
   320,617,341,214      MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L1_HIT                                       (45.13%)
    12,006,256,563      MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L2_HIT                                       (45.12%)
     6,499,185,771      MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L3_HIT                                       (45.15%)
   321,649,950,616      MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.ALL_LOADS                                     (45.17%)
   196,989,430,826      MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.ALL_STORES                                     (45.21%)
         9,709,983      MEM_LOAD_L3_MISS_RETIRED.REMOTE_DRAM                                     (45.29%)
        52,088,603      MEM_LOAD_L3_MISS_RETIRED.REMOTE_FWD                                     (45.40%)

     120.087210363 seconds time elapsed
    
l2 miss % = 6,877,904,780 / 18,698,108,046 =  36.7%
l3 miss % = 646,751,270 / 6,877,904,780 = 9.4%


